# get posts of followed users with acts_as_follower

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 models in my Rails 3 app

User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_followable
  acts_as_follower

  has_many :posts

end
```

Post:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

So, I can fetch users that I follow: `User.find(1).following_users`

But how to fetch posts of followed users? Something like `User.find(1).following_users.posts`

Comment: Do you want all the posts in a single collection?  Or do you need the posts grouped to the user somehow?

Comment: I need all the posts as a collection without grouping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User.find(1).following_users just returns and arel reference, see here:

https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower/blob/master/lib/acts_as_follower/follower.rb#L59

So,

```
User.find(1).following_users.includes(:posts)
```

should include the posts for the users in the query, but this will return an array of users.   The following should work, loop through the users that are returned and collect their posts into an array

```
posts = User.find(1).following_users.includes(:posts).collect{|u| u.posts}.flatten
```

Answer (score 0):

```
User.following_users.collect{|u| u.posts}
```

This should work