# Create a feed with acts_as_follower

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have three models

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_followable
    has_many :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :startdate
    acts_as_followable
    belongs_to :place
    belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_followable
    acts_as_follower
    has_many :events
end
```

I need to do two things:

- get a homogeneous sorted list of events for followed places or users
- get a homogeneous sorted list of events for followed places and users and events without duplicates

So for instance

`User.find(1).following_places.includes(:events).collect{|p| p.events}.flatten.sort{|a,b| a.startdate <=> b.startdate}`

should return a list of events for all of the places a user is following, sorted by date.  The issue with this, if I am understanding correctly, is that the collect, flatten, and sort occur in ruby instead of SQL.

The second part should look something like the following, and ideally occur entirely in SQL as well:

```
user = User.find(1)
(user..following_places.includes(:events).collect{|p| p.events}.flatten +
user.following_users.includes(:events).collect{|p| p.events}.flatten +
user.following_events).sort{|a,b| a.startdate <=> b.startdate}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7921682/394184) is close, but not quite what I am looking for.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using order?

```
User.find(1).following_places.includes(:events).order('events.startdate ASC')
```